# asp.net Form Authentication across sub domains

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, form-authentication

This should be simple but i dont know what i am missing.

I am using forms authentication across sub domains,

I have a parent domain, `parent.com` and two sub domains `portal.parent.com` and `auth.parent.com`. `auth.parent.com` is the authenticating site.

When an unautherized users access `portal.parent.com/site`, They will be redirected to `auth.parent.com/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2fsite`, after a successfull login they are redirected to`auth.parent.com/site`,  and that the problem. I was expecting to be redirected back to `portal.parent.com/site`.

my configuration on boths sites

`portal.parent.com/site` web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="http://auth.parent.com/Account/LogOn" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" domain=".parent.com" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

`auth.parent.com/site` web.config

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" domain=".parent.com" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

other than the return url, the authentication is working fine, i.e If i go back to `portal.parent.com/site`I can see the user authenticated and i can access the Identity info.

I was reading this question [Forms Authentication across Sub-Domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608120/forms-authentication-across-sub-domains)

But didnt help specifically in my case.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this [Forms Authentication ReturnUrl and subdomain for single sign-on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972195/forms-authentication-returnurl-and-subdomain-for-single-sign-on)
, That solved my problem.

I am not sure if that is the best way to do it, though.