# Forms Authentication - Redirect Back to Original Domain

Tags: asp.net, redirect, authentication, forms-authentication, subdomain

Example:

Application = https://test2.mytest.com/MyApplication/Download.aspx

The application has forms authentication enabled in the web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="https://test.mytest.com/Login/" name=".ASPXAUTH"/>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

When accessing the application it correctly redirect to the login page:
https://test.mytest.com/Login/?ReturnUrl=%2fMyApplication%2fDownload.aspx

However, after successfully logging in it goes to:
https://test.mytest.com/MyApplication/Download.aspx
instead of
https://test2.mytest.com/MyApplication/Download.aspx

It is using the sub-domain of where the login application is (test.mytest.com), not the sub-domain of the original request (test2.mytest.com). 
Is there anyway to have forms authentication redirect back to the original requesting sub-domain instead of the sub-domain that the login app is on?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is certainly possible, but you'll need to make changes on both the authenticating sub domain and the sub domain requiring authentication.

**The sub domain requiring authentication.**
The issue you're having is that when an anonymous user attempts to access a secured resource  ASP.NET forms authentication redirects them to the login page and appends the original requested resource in the "ReturnURL" query string **but this ReturnURL parameter is a relative URL**.

So to get this to work in the way you want, you'll need to manipulate the ReturnURL parameter to indicate in some way that the return is to a different site.

One way to do this is to manipulate the ReturnURL using an HttpHandler to hook into the PostAuthenticateRequest, as detailed in this article, [Forms Authentication With Absolute Return URLs](http://blogs.freshlogicstudios.com/Posts/View.aspx?Id=cb739183-6a0b-46bc-9179-22aed8e60433).

**The authenticating sub domain**
To enable redirection to the calling subdomain you'll need to set the [enableCrossAppRedirects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.enablecrossappredirects.asp) attribute to "true" in the forms section of the web.config to allow redirection to a URL in another web application. Be aware of the implications of this though as it leaves you open to [open redirection attacks](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/security/preventing-open-redirection-attacks).

An alternative and more secure approach to just setting the sub domain address directly on the ReturnURL (helping prevent open redirection attacks) is to modify the ReturnURL to contain a known parameter in the querystring and then modify the Application_EndRequest in the global.asax.cs of the authenticating subdomian as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4998277/667562) and [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/dfindley/archive/2007/02/06/fix-returnurl-when-sharing-forms-authentication-with-multiple-web-applications.aspx) to rewrite the Response.RedirectLocation.